# how to using log4j2 to send some extra infomation(object) to custom appender?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I using log4j2 in my project something like controller tower.
and use some custom log appenders for sending websocket event, snmp trap event, insert to database.

I want to send more infomation to custom log appender something like error code, source node, snmp Oid, job id, etc...

using log4j2, is there any way to send more info to log appender?

Just like this:

**logging part**:  logger.info(customObject);

**snmp appender**:  get oid from customObject, get message from customObject

**websocket appender**: get jobid from customObject, get message from customObject

**database appender**: get error code from customObject, get message from customObject

sorry for my poor english.
and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: looks like [Thread Context](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html) can do it. but it is designed for thread Fish Tagging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution.
log4j2 have Message interface.
and I can implements this interface to send custom infomation.
just like

```
public class CustomLogMessage implements Message {
  private String oid;
  private long errorCode;
  private String msg;
....
}
```

and in custom log appenders, I can cast message to CustomLogMessage, and get info.
just like

```
@Override
public void append(LogEvent event) {
    Message message = event.getMessage();
    if(message instanceof CustomLogMessage) {
        CustomLogMessage customLogMessage = (CustomLogMessage) message;
        System.out.println(customLogMessage.getOid());
        System.out.println(customLogMessage.getErrorCode());
        System.out.println(customLogMessage.getFormattedMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Log4j will always send strings and doesn't offer serialization facilities.

I suggest that you serialize your objects before calling log4j. You could use a serilization format compatble with the technologies.

Maybe you can serializeyour objects to JSOJN with the jackson library.

Comment: Log4j 2 allows you to log any Object, not just Strings. This is one of the reasons why the Log4j 2 API is superior to slf4j.